# Trying to solve a system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Let the following system $X'=AX+b(t)$ be a system of differential equations, where:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-4\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix}\cos2t\\0\end{pmatrix}$

Then When trying to solve, the roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix are complex, therefore I'm going to use:

$$D=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}$$

since $\lambda_{1,2}=1\pm2i$ then $D=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\-2&1\end{pmatrix}$
 and $P=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$, then $A=PDP^{-1}$

$X'=AX=PDP^{-1}X\implies P^{-1}X'=DP^{-1}X$
if we note $P^{-1}X=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}$ then a matrix of fundamental solutions for the new system is: $M(t)=e^t\begin{pmatrix}cos(2t)&sin(2t)\\-sin(2t)&cos(2t)\end{pmatrix}$

Then $X=Pe^t\begin{pmatrix}cos(2t)&sin(2t)\\sin(2t)&cos(2t)\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}$

All in all we get: $$X=e^t\begin{pmatrix}2c_1cos(2t)+2c_2sin(2t)\\-c_1sin(2t)-c_2sin(2t)\end{pmatrix}$$

But that is not correct, what am I missing?

Comment: It makes no sense to use a full matrix $D$ when $D$ should be diagonal. You need to use the eigendecomposition $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-2i & 2i\\
1 & 1
\end{array}
\right) \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1-2i & 0\\
0 & 1+2i
\end{array}
\right) \left( \begin{array}{cc}
-2i & 2i\\
1 & 1
\end{array}\right)^{-1}$ with a diagonal matrix in the middle.

Comment: You keep leaving a minus sign out of the fundamental matrix in your questions. As well, $\exp(tA)=P\exp(tD)P^{-1}$. Note, too, that you’ve only solved the related homogeneous equation $X'=AX$. You still need to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation.

Comment: @Christoph A $2\times2$ real matrix with complex eigenvalues is similar to a matrix of the form $\small{\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}}$. The OP’s decomposition is perfectly good.

Comment: @amd I see, you're right. I guess I'm sometimes ignorant of such things which work only in very special cases, like $2 \times 2$.

Comment: @amd right, i'm sorry, And how do I search for the particular solution?

Comment: @Moo not really